# Numpy delete slow and paradoxal

Tags: python, numpy, performance

Let's imagine you have a wide range of element.
You randomly take one of these and copy the value to the left one and then repeat untill there is only on value for all the element.

For each iteration we have the choice of deleting the element and its neighbourg or keeping them. I thought the former was faster because you avoid choosing multiple times the same element.

I have tried to put it in a simple code:

```
nbrs = np.arange(1000)
def f(arr):
    index=random.randint(0,998)
    arr[index+1]=arr[index]
    arr=np.delete(arr,[index,index+1]) # -> optionnal delete element
    return np.amax(arr)

import time
start_time = time.perf_counter()
while f(nbrs)>1:
    f(nbrs)
end_time = time.perf_counter()
```

with delete I have an execution time of ~20s
without delete I have an execution time of ~7s

=> ??? why is it longer when you reduce the total number of element as long as you proceed ?
Is there a mistake in my logic ?

Comment: `np.delete` does not act in-place.  It makes a whole new array, which requires copying values to the right and left of the deleted items.  Or to put it another way, `delete` is really 'give me a new array that contains everything except these [...]`.

Comment: In fact I'm generating maze and would like to speed-up the process (35s for 40k case). I think I'm wasting a lot of time due to non deletion of already chosen items. Is there a way to delete item from an array with the index without re-creating the whole array ?

Comment: No, not with numpy arrays. Usually "how to speed up"-questions require the actual problem to be answerable.

Comment: Understood but I did not know it was not answerable ...my bad

Comment: You might explore marking elements for 'deletion' without actually deleting them.  The 'bookkeeping' might be a bit tedious, but overall it could be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with list of already tested index, speed up time : 10x.
Seems trivial in the end.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

nbrs = np.arange(10)
av=[]
def f(arr=nbrs):
    index=random.randint(0,8)
    if index not in av:
        value = np.amax(arr)
        arr[index+1]=arr[index]
        arr=np.delete(arr,[index,index+1])
        av.append(index)
    return np.amax(arr)
```